# WinRT & Facebook SDK - ProfilePicture : how to determine when the image is about to be rendered?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there any way you could determine an `Image`'s source has been set, without taking advantage of the `ImageOpened` event?

I'm using `Facebook SDK`, to be more specific, the `ProfilePicture` control, which hasn't this event (not sure if it's related to `Image` actually) and I'd like to know when the image (profile picture) was downloaded and was about to be shown.

P.S. : I tagged [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) for a wider "audience", altough I'm looking for an answer that would work for [windows-runtime](/questions/tagged/windows-runtime) apps, but I'll take my chances...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any way to do this with the ProfilePicture control. Instead, I am now using an `Image` in XAML which can determine when image is about to be rendered with the `ImageOpened` event.

First, I get the url string of the image with `Graph Search API` :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?redirect=false&width=320&height=320
```

The complete method looks like this :

```
public static async Task<string> GetProfilePictureUrlAsync()
    {
        dynamic jsonData = await _facebookClient.GetTaskAsync("https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?redirect=false&width=320&height=320");

        JObject result = JObject.Parse(jsonData.ToString());

        var array = new JArray(result["data"]);

        return (string) array[0].SelectToken("url");
    }
```

Then I create an `URI` and assign it to the image control :

```
ProfileImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(await FacebookUtility.GetProfilePictureUrlAsync(), UriKind.Absolute));
```

(`ProfileImage` is the name of the control I have in XAML)

Hope this helps the others who might run into this problem :)